# Are there any good Java API for facebook?

Tags: java, facebook, facebook-java-api, restfb

I've played around a bit with **twitter4j** and found it absolutely wonderful. Now I've been looking into the equivalent for facebook but so far haven't had much luck finding a decent project.

I looked into [**facebook-java-api**](http://code.google.com/p/facebook-java-api/) but it appears that they break their API from release to release. I consider this unacceptable.

I'm currently playing around a bit with [**RestFB**](http://restfb.com/) and the API seems decent so far but I've been having some connection problems.

I'm just looking for a simple library that lets me post status updates, send direct messages and get a list of friends through minimal coding effort.

Has anyone had any success using a java API for facebook and if so, what are you using?  Thanks.

Comment: FB Graph has recently come out. The REST based API is now the "Old API" I'd read up on that b4 going into the REST API

Comment: I'm the maintainer of RestFB. What kind of problems were you seeing?

Comment: I created a new FacebookClient object using my account token and then tried running the sample fetchObject code for cocacola. It would always throw an exception with an unrecognized status exception. Connecting through firefox to the same Graph API url would return Status 200 OK.

Comment: If you post your stack trace here or on http://groups.google.com/group/restfb, I'll give you a hand figuring out what's up.  The examples should work just fine; I'm guessing this is something small like a copy-paste issue.  Thanks!

Comment: Yeah, I assume I am doing something wrong.  Thanks, I'll get around to posting it there soon :-)

Comment: It's a old question, but I've still the same doubt. I've found spring-social-facebook besides restFB. Does anybody has a recommendation on which one seems better for the updated API? Not sure, but spring restFB seems more like a wrapper (which is what I want) and Spring seems more complex, handling credentials/tokens storage, authentication mechanism and so on. My perfect library would receive the user access token and would provide me methods for invoking graph endpoints

Answer (score 1):

Did you try out the social templates recently announced at [Socializing Spring Applications](http://blog.springsource.com/2010/11/03/socializing-spring-applications/)? The article refers to a recent milestone release of [Spring Social](http://www.springsource.org/spring-social) and the code examples look nice.